# Field size job.run_frequency

Tags: database

Is it possible to make the size of the field run_frequency in the table job greater?
It is now 8, but if would be 10 then the translation for 'daily' will not be truncated (not for me in this case).

Comment: Any reason you can't just use sql to do this? Alternatively, perhaps you could use some translation techniques for the presentation of that value rather than changing it in the db?

Comment: I have chosen to change the translation because i dont want to change the database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you did, but might as well document it for others below.

Comment: I work with Transifex, there you can translated CiviCRM.. I have changed my translation (9 characters) to another (8 characters). This is the first translation i see where the databasefieldsize will truncate the translation (to 8 for this field).